# How to insert list of item for one document in cosmos db C#?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Return list of items:

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    string strCommandtext = "SELECT CONCAT([name],'_',[Number]) FROM [newTable]";
    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strCommandtext, connection);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds);

    foreach (DataRow drRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        controllerData.Add(drRow[0].ToString());
    }
}
            string demo = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(controllerData);

return demo;
```

Insert into document db / cosmos db

```
 await client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("databaseID", "collectionID"), demo);
```

but it throws an error:

> {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: Cosmos DB is a document store. What is the shape of your documents? You can't just store a list of strings as a document. Also FYI since you did a select with no `where` condition, this means you can have an unbounded number of strings returned from your SQL database. Meaning, you run the risk of storing more than the maximum (2MB) within a single document.

Comment: I want to store it as json format

Comment: Your code isn't doing anything JSON-like, currently. It's just taking a list of strings and trying to store it as such. As you've seen, this doesn't work. JSON requires some type of key/value-pair structure. And for any kind of list, you'll need an array within a document (again, unbounded arrays are a "code smell" with document stores - eventually you'll run into trouble if you exceed the max document size).

Comment: any sample code you can provide will be helpful :) thanks in advance

Comment: thanks for pointing doc size i will tackle it

Comment: The Cosmos DB documentation pages have many tutorials, including examples for how to write content, by creating a class and adding json serialization to it. I'd start by looking there.

Comment: updated question same as tutorial still getting Object reference null error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `CreateDocumentAsync()` is only for single document.

According to your description, we can use bulk executor library to achieve this.

[Bulk Executor](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-bulkexecutor-dotnet-getting-started)